# Square numbers with a form of $p^{2n+1} + q^{2n+1}$, where p, q are prime numbers and n is a positive integer

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

Recently I came across a difficult problem:

> Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer and $p, q$ be different prime numbers. Can $p^{2n+1} + q^{2n+1}$ be a square number?

When I wrote a python program, I found some solutions like (11, 37), (1801, 56999), (6637, 86291), and so on for $n = 1$. For $n > 1$, however, I could find no solutions. Are there any solutions for $n > 1$? I tried to prove or give counterexamples (perhaps $p+q \mid p^{2n+1} + q^{n+1}$ is a useful fact?), but I have no idea to solve this problem.

Context: When I was a high-school student, I see a similar problem: "Prove $p^{2n} + q^{2n}$ is not a square number." (An easier problem than the topic problem.) I forgot about this problem recently, but I came across the problem when I was reading a book (mock exam) I read in my high-school days. Perhaps the phrase "came across" was a bit inappropriate, because I changed the original problem into a more difficult problem when I was a high-school student.

Comment: Interesting (+1)  What's the source of this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a sensible solution?

Comment: @lulu It is a FAQ - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796253/when-the-sum-of-two-cubesor-2n1th-powered-number-of-different-prime-numbers-i?noredirect=1). I like the remark "The question is out of my curiosity."

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks!  I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: "Missing context" does not fit as close-vote reason here , but it might be a duplicate.

Comment: The range $p<q<10^5$ and $1\le n\le 10$ gives $7$ solutions , all with $n=1$

Comment: @Peter Another possibility is that the results on the generalised Fermat equation $x^p+y^q=z^r$ with $p=q=2n+1$ and $r=2$ will help, and that it doesn't matter that $x$ and $y$ are prime (I have no time to check now).